# $(document).ready has stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test");                         
    document.getElementById("currentemp").onclick = disableThem;
});
function disableThem(){
    if (document.getElementById("currentemp").checked)  {
        document.getElementById("edate_m").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("edate_y").disabled = true;
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById("edate_m").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("edate_y").disabled = false;
    }
}
$(function(){
    alert("test2");        
    if (document.getElementById("currentemp").checked)  {
        document.getElementById("edate_m").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("edate_y").disabled = true;
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById("edate_m").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("edate_y").disabled = false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Hello. This script was working a few weeks ago. Now I noticed it stopped working even though I havent changed it. Usually when my javascript stops working its because I have tons of javascript and sometimes the functions cross over each other. But I've put in alert boxes and it seems it doesnt even load as it should.

Any ideas for debugging?

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery with this ugly direct DOM access?

Comment: Does jquery get loaded? What error message does the javascript console  (or firebug or similar) give?

Comment: Does any javascript work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are you sure the path to your jQuery file is correct? Or the file hasn't been removed or moved etc by anyone else? I do have to ask too, if you're using jQuerys `$(document).ready()` why are you using `document.getElementByID` everywhere when you could just use `$("#edate_m")` / `$("#edate_y")` - if you're going to use jQuery you might as well simplify the rest of it too.

Comment: Could you show how you are including jquery.js? (Also, it shouldn't stop it working, but why do you have two document ready handlers, and given that you do have two why not use the same syntax for both?)

Comment: Does `alert("test2")` work? If not, as @mpartel said, check if jquery is loading or just for the heck of it try `window.onload` to see if there is something else wrong.

Comment: This worked previously. Now it doesnt. None of those alert boxes appear.

Comment: @DopeyDatabaseMaster - Please check your browser's JavaScript console for error messages. Seriously. You ask for debugging ideas and that's the most basic step. When no code appears to run, 99% of the times it's just a simple syntax error clearly displayed in the console.

Comment: There must be an error in the JS above specified code or inside it

Answer (score 3):

1. Put your custom function before document.ready, just in case.
2. You do not need two ready functions.
3. Make sure the elements are available in your page and the selectors are valid.

Here is your simplified code:

```
function disableThem() {
    var state = $("#currentemp").is(":checked");
    $("#edate_m").attr("disabled", state);
    $("#edate_y").attr("disabled", state);
}

$(function() {
    disableThem();
    $("#currentemp").onclick = disableThem;
});
```

Comment: The location of a function definition does not matter, since `ready` is only called when the page has fully loaded. Also, when a block of code is parsed, the function definitions are always executed first, so: `foo();function foo(){alert(0)}` will not break.

Answer (score 0):

you example works for me see: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/KXCM3/

Are you sure that jquery is loaded? Is the following code `true`?

```
alert(jQuery !== undefined);
```

Comment: True yeah.

Bizarre! Must be some other js messing with it. See I predominantly a backend developer so I am taking over someones elses work and its really sloppy.

Comment: does something show in in the console? Could you review the code what else is being done with `currentemp` and `edate_m` and `edate_y`

Comment: I renamed it to cur to match the value i record in the backend. I also validate those values.

Comment: so you also renamed the `id="currentemp"` to `id="cur"`?

Comment: Yeah I did. I think the problem isnt with the script but with an error somewhere else that prevents it from working cause when I get error from an asp script on that page, I get the pop up boxes.